# Can you make a std::shared_ptr manage an array allocated with new T[]?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Can you make a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) point to an array?  For example,

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[10]);
```

If not, then why not? One reason I am already aware of is one can not increment/decrement the `std::shared_ptr`. Hence it cannot be used like a normal pointer to an array.

Comment: FWIT, you may also consider just using `std::vector`. You'd have to be careful to pass the array around using references so that you don't make copies of it. Syntax for accessing data is cleaner than shared_ptr, and resizing it is very very easy. And you get all the STL goodness should you ever want it.

Comment: If the size of the array is determined at compile time, you might also consider using `std::array`. It is *almost* the same as a raw array, but with proper semantics for use in most library components. Especially objects of that type are destroyed with `delete`, not `delete[]`. And unlike `vector`, it stores the data directly in the object, so you get no extra allocation.

Answer (score 326, accepted):

With **C++17**, `shared_ptr` can be used to manage a dynamically allocated array. The `shared_ptr` template argument in this case must be `T[N]` or `T[]`. So you may write

```
shared_ptr<int[]> sp(new int[10]);
```

From n4659, [[util.smartptr.shared.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.smartptr.shared.const)

> ```
>   template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* p);
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `Y` shall be a complete type. The expression `delete[] p`, when `T` is an array type, or `delete p`, when `T` is not an array type, shall have well-defined behavior, and shall not throw exceptions.
>   ...
>   *Remarks:* When `T` is an array type, this constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless the expression `delete[] p` is well-formed and either `T` is `U[N]` and `Y(*)[N]` is convertible to `T*`, or `T` is
>   `U[]` and `Y(*)[]` is convertible to `T*`. ...

To support this, the member type [`element_type`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.smartptr.shared#1) is now defined as

```
using element_type = remove_extent_t<T>;
```

Array elements can be access using [`operator[]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/util.smartptr.shared.obs#8)

> ```
>   element_type& operator[](ptrdiff_t i) const;
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `get() != 0 && i >= 0`. If `T` is `U[N]`, `i < N`.
>   ...
>   *Remarks:* When `T` is not an array type, it is unspecified whether this member function is declared. If it is declared, it is unspecified what its return type is, except that the declaration (although not necessarily the definition) of the function shall be well formed.

---

**Prior to C++17**, `shared_ptr` could **not** be used to manage dynamically allocated arrays. By default, `shared_ptr` will call `delete` on the managed object when no more references remain to it. However, when you allocate using `new[]` you need to call `delete[]`, and not `delete`, to free the resource.

In order to correctly use `shared_ptr` with an array, you must supply a custom deleter.

```
template< typename T >
struct array_deleter
{
  void operator ()( T const * p)
  { 
    delete[] p; 
  }
};
```

Create the shared_ptr as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[10], array_deleter<int>());
```

Now `shared_ptr` will correctly call `delete[]` when destroying the managed object.

The custom deleter above may be replaced by

- the [`std::default_delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) partial specialization for array types

  ```
  std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>());
  ```
- a lambda expression

  ```
  std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[10], [](int *p) { delete[] p; });
  ```

Also, unless you actually need share onwership of the managed object, a `unique_ptr` is better suited for this task, since it has a partial specialization for array types.

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> up(new int[10]); // this will correctly call delete[]
```

---

#### Changes introduced by the C++ Extensions for Library Fundamentals

Another pre-C++17 alternative to the ones listed above was provided by the [Library Fundamentals Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lib_extensions), which augmented `shared_ptr` to allow it to work out of the box for the cases when it owns an array of objects. The current draft of the `shared_ptr` changes slated for this TS can be found in [N4082](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4082.pdf). These changes will be accessible via the `std::experimental` namespace, and included in the `<experimental/memory>` header. A few of the relevant changes to support `shared_ptr` for arrays are:

— The definition of the member type `element_type` changes

> <del>typedef T element_type;</del>
>
> ```
>  typedef typename remove_extent<T>::type element_type;
> ```

— Member `operator[]` is being added

> ```
>  element_type& operator[](ptrdiff_t i) const noexcept;
> ```

— Unlike the `unique_ptr` partial specialization for arrays, both `shared_ptr<T[]>` and `shared_ptr<T[N]>` will be valid and both will result in `delete[]` being called on the managed array of objects.

> ```
>  template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y* p);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `Y` shall be a complete type. The expression `delete[] p`, when `T` is an array type, or `delete p`, when `T` is not an array type, shall be well-formed, shall have well defined behavior, and shall not throw exceptions. When `T` is `U[N]`, `Y(*)[N]` shall be convertible to `T*`; when `T` is `U[]`, `Y(*)[]` shall be convertible to `T*`; otherwise, `Y*` shall be convertible to `T*`.

Comment: +1, remark: There is also Boost's [`shared-array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Praetorian.
Can you please tell me how can i assign different values to the int array which shared_ptr is pointing to?

Comment: @tshah06 [`shared_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) returns a pointer to the managed object. So you can use it as `sp.get()[0] = 1; ... sp.get()[9] = 10;`

Comment: ALT: `std::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>() );` see also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete

Comment: There's always the option to declare a class that contains the array as a member variable, and pass around objects of the class via a shared_ptr.  That avoids the delete-vs-delete[] issue, with no overhead except a few extra lines of code.

Comment: @Jeremy If the size is known at compile time there's no need to write a class for that, `std::shared_ptr<std::array<int,N>>` should be enough.

Comment: Why does `unique_ptr` get that partial specialization but `shared_ptr` does not?

Comment: Those are not C++14 changes, those are Library Fundamentals TS changes

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. I cannot tell whether I need to do something special or not.

Comment: @Praetorian I cited your answer [in a question about the T(N) syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447401/why-allow-shared-ptrtn). If you have any thoughts on that, feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Could I also use `std::make_shared<int[]>(10)` when using c++17?

Answer (score 32):

A possibly easier alternative that you might be able to use is `shared_ptr<vector<int>>`.

Comment: Yes it is. Or a vector is a superset of an array - it has the same in-memory representation (plus metadata) but is resizable. There aren't really any situations where you want an array but can't use a vector.

Comment: The difference, here, is that the vector size is anymore static, and the access to the data will be done with a double indirection. If performance is not the critical issue, this works, otherwise sharing an array may have its own reason.

Comment: Then you can probably use `shared_ptr<array<int, 6>>`.

Comment: The other difference is that it's *slightly* bigger and slower than a raw array. Generally not really an issue but let's not pretend that 1 == 1.1.

Comment: There are situations where the source of the data in the array means that it is unwieldily or unnecessary to convert to a vector; such as when getting a frame from a camera. (Or, that's my understanding, anyway)