# Benefits of using BOOST shared_array over shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I want to use **BOOST Smart pointer** for memory management in my application. But I'm not sure which smart pointer should I use for dynamically allocated array `shared_ptr` or `shared_array`.

According to the `BOOST` doc **Starting with Boost release 1.53, shared_ptr can be used to hold a pointer to a dynamically allocated array.**

So I'm just wondering now what purpose user should use **shared_array** instead of **shared_ptr**.

Comment: Why not `std::vector` for dynamic arrays and `std::unique_ptr` for objects?

Comment: I have a 3rd party library functions which are taking raw pointer as argument, so I can't use vector.

Comment: `std::vector` has the same contiguous layout like a plain array. `std::vector::data()` and `&vec[0]` allow you to extract the pointer to that array.

Comment: True, but just curious is there any disadvantage to use `vector` over `share_ptr`.

Comment: Quite to the contrary, `shared_ptr` should only ever be used as a last resort option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before boost 1.53, `boost::shared_ptr` is to be used for a pointer to a single object.

After 1.53, since `boost::shared_ptr` can be used for array types, I think it's pretty much the same as `boost::shared_array`.

But for now I don't think it's a good idea to use array type in `shared_ptr`, because C++11's `std::shared_ptr` has a bit different behavior on array type compared to `boost::shared_ptr`.

See [shared_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used) as reference for the difference.

So if you want your code compatible with C++11 and use `std::shared_ptr` instead, you need to use it carefully. Because:

- Code look like below gets compile error (you need a custom deleter), while boost's version is OK.

  ```
   std::shared_ptr<int[]> a(new int[5]); // Compile error

   // You need to write like below:
   std::shared_ptr<int> b(new int[5], std::default_delete<int[]>());

   boost::shared_ptr<int[]> c(new int[5]); // OK
  ```
- However, if you write code like below, you are likely to get segment fault

  ```
   std::shared_ptr<T> a(new T[5]); // segment fault
   boost::shared_ptr<T> b(new T[5]); // segment fault
  ```

The syntax of `shared_ptr` in `std` and `boost` are different and not compatible.

Additional information: consider [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html), which is a pretty fast implementation for dynamic allocated objects in vector. Just FYI in case you want this feature.

Comment: thanks, I agree that to make it **C+11** compatible I should go either with custom **deleter** option or **boost shared_array** but I'm looking for any additional benefits which I'll get after using `shared_array` over `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I don't know if any additional benefits exist for `shared_array`. And in the future C++ *may* introduce `shared_ptr<T[]>`, then it will be compatible with boost. But above all, it's better to think if you really need `shared_array`, maybe a *scoped* array is enough to suits the need, the you can use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead.