# Can I safely replace boost::shared_array<T> with std::shared_ptr<T[]>?

Tags: boost, c++14, shared-ptr

I'm working on a C++14 codebase which uses boost::shared_array. If I understand correctly, `scoped_array` and `shared_array` are the `new[]`-allocated equivalents of `scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr`, which themselves are mostly deprecated by the availability of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

So, can I just use `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` instead of `boost::shared_array<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

**With C++14: No, you can't.**

Before C++17, `std::shared_ptr` does not properly work for arrays. But - it does work if you provide a custom deleter; so you can define:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> make_shared_array(std::size_t n)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T> { new T[n], std::default_delete<T[]>{} };
}
```

which [works](https://godbolt.org/z/fTnfnqfrq) (although there may be a potential leak in there if the shared pointer constructor fails).

---

When you use C++17 or later - you can, it seems, safely define:

```
template <typename T>
using shared_array = std::shared_ptr<T[]>;
```

Related questions:

- [Benefits of using BOOST shared_array over shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25968849/1593077)
- [shared_ptr to an array : should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13061979/1593077)