# Is safe boost::multi_array_ref returned by a function?

Tags: c++, function, boost, boost-multi-array

I'm trying to use boost::multi_array_ref to use a block of contiguous data in my code. But I worry about if I use the code like below, the 1d C array won't be confirmed to save:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
boost::multi_array_ptr<double, 2> test(int N,int c,int d) {
    double *data = new double[N];
    boost::multi_array_ref<double, 2> a(data, boost::extents[c][d]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            a[i][j] = 10 * i + j;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    boost::multi_array_ptr<double, 2> a = test(100000000,10000,10000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            std::cout << a[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is right and I want to use `std::unique_ptr` to replace the C style array, but the Visual Studio told me:

```
no instance of constructor "boost::multi_array_ref<T, NumDims>::multi_array_ref [with T=double, NumDims=2Ui64]" matches the argument list
```

I don't know which kind of parameter boost::multi_array_ref need. Why the `std::unique_ptr` can't be use as parameter but C style array can? Can I use C style array without worry? Is safe boost::multi_array_ref returned by a function?

I'm sure that it will cause memory leak,but how to solve it?

Comment: What is `multi_array_ptr`? There is not such thing. Do you mean `multi_array_ref` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double *data = new double[N];
```

That's a raw pointer and no-one owns the allocation. You're correct that it leads to memory leaks. However, since you want to include ownership, why use `multi_array`**`_ref`**?

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bdo7E5f7E)**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

auto test(int c, int d) {
    boost::multi_array<double, 2> a(boost::extents[c][d]);
    std::iota(a.data(), a.data()+a.num_elements(), 0);
    return a;
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main()
{
    boost::multi_array<double, 2> a = test(4, 5);

    fmt::print("{}\n", a);
    fmt::print("{}\n", test(3, 6));
    fmt::print("{}\n", test(6, 2));
}
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

And has no memory leaks.

### If you **need** the multi-array-ref:

You might hack your way around with owning smart pointers:

```
using ARef    = boost::multi_array_ref<double, 2>;
using ARefPtr = boost::shared_ptr<ARef>;
```

Now you can allocate the data like you did before - but without the leak:

```
auto test(int c, int d) {
    auto data = boost::shared_ptr<double[]>(new double[c*d]);
```

> See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25969615/85371) for details and compatibility with `std::shared_ptr`

And Use the aliasing constructor to share ownership of data while changing
the apparent element type to ARef:

```
    auto a = ARefPtr(data, new ARef(data.get(), boost::extents[c][d]));
    std::iota(a->data(), a->data() + a->num_elements(), 0);
    return a;
}

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
int main()
{
    ARefPtr a = test(4, 5);

    fmt::print("{}\n", *a);
    fmt::print("{}\n", *test(3, 6));
    fmt::print("{}\n", *test(6, 2));
}
```

Of course, now you're dealing with smart pointers, so you need more de-references. See it **[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/EP18jcfcz)**:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

Comment: I use boost::multi_array_ref to get 2d array's memeory contiguous. Thank you.

Comment: But it is also contiguous with `multi_array`

Comment: Emm,I'm newer to boost, I have known it now.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a perfect solution for me [without boost](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op).

A self-defined 2d array(Matrix) class

The solution with boost is sehe's answer.

Comment: How does this solve the problem? You still have expiring local data in the function that is not available outside.