# Is calling delete operator on a memory allocated by new[] operator undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, standards, c++14, delete-operator

I am pretty much sure it is but if I am interpreting correctly the standard (Section 18.6.1.2 new.delete.array) mentions that:

> void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;
> pointer.
>
> . **13 Default behavior: Calls operator delete(ptr)**

Since in its default behavior delete[] just calls its delete(ptr) equivalent why should it matter which version is called?
I tried with a sample code to verify this and it crashes making it more evident that mismatching new[] and delete indeed lead to bad things

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class foo{
    public:
        void bar(){
            std::cout << "foo's bar" << std::endl;
        }
        ~foo(){
            std::cout << "foo dies after this" << std::endl;
        }
};
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<foo> x(new foo[10]);
    return 0;
}
```

How should the above quoted line from the standard be interpreted?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used

Comment: `delete` does more than calling `::operator delete`, and `delete[]` does more than calling `::operator delete[]`. It's unclear to me whether you understand this. If you do, can you please edit your question to address it?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am aware of the nuisance of creating shared_ptr that way. Infact that is why I have explicitely chosen that example. My main question is around interpreting the language standard.

Comment: It is accurate, it describes the operation of the *library function*.  Calling the destructor of all the array elements is the job of the compiler, not the library function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing the `delete[]` expression with the function `operator delete[]`. When you write:

```
delete[] p;
```

then the compiler issues code which will call destructors for all objects in the array pointed to by `p`, and then call the deallocation function `operator delete[]` with the argument `p`. As per the documentation you've quoted, the default `::operator delete[]` calls `::operator delete`. So the following calls to the deallocation functions are equivalent when default implementations are used:

```
::operator delete[] (p);
::operator delete(p);
```

But the following are **not** equivalent, because they do much more than just call the deallocation functions:

```
delete[] p;
delete p;
```

Comment: Thanx. That clarifies my question :)