# How to index into C++ shared_ptr/unique_ptr array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

As inspired by [Demo of shared ptr array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used)

I got the first two lines to work:

```
std::shared_ptr<string> sp( new string[3], []( string *p ) { delete[] p; } );
*sp = "john";
auto p = &(* sp);
++p = new string("Paul");
++p = new string("Mary");
for(auto q = &(*sp); q <= p; q++) cout << *q << endl;
```

(1) Can someone show me how to access subsequent elements of my array and print them out with a for loop?

My for loop does not print anything with MSVC V19 and and g++ v4.9 prints "john" but not "Paul" and "Mary" and then gives me a segmentation fault.

Now after some more google/bing searching I found some discussions suggesting I should use `unique_ptr` if I are not sharing it.

So I got to experimenting some more and this works:

```
  const int len=3;
  std::unique_ptr<string[]> up( new string[len] ); // this will correctly call delete[]
  up[0] = "john";
  up[1] = "paul";
  up[2] = "mary";
  for(int ii = 0; ii < len; ++ii) cout << up[ii] << endl;
```

(2) Is there a way to print the array up without hard coding the length in a constant? I was hoping that there was a way to make the new C++ for loop syntax work but it appears only work on `std::array` and `std::vector`.

(3) Is there is an easier way to initialize this array? Perhaps with an initializer list?

Comment: What about simply using a `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: After `++p = new string("Mary");`, `p` points to the newly allocated string, and is in no way related to the memory held by `sp`. Your `for` loop then exhibits undefined behavior by way of comparing unrelated pointers. You might have meant something like `*(++p) = "Paul";`

Comment: You can simply do `sp.get()[0]`, `sp.get()[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

To access subsequent elements use the [`shared_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) member function

```
std::shared_ptr<string> sp( new string[3], std::default_delete<string[]>() );
sp.get()[0] = "John";
sp.get()[1] = "Paul";
sp.get()[2] = "Mary";
for(auto q = sp.get(); q < sp.get() + 3; q++) cout << *q << endl;
```

The problem with dereferencing the `shared_ptr` is that it'll return a `string&`, but you want to get access to the underlying pointer in order to be able to index to next element.

You can also initialize the `shared_ptr` array upon construction using list initialization

```
std::shared_ptr<string> sp( new string[3]{"John", "Paul", "Mary"}, 
                            std::default_delete<string[]>() );
```

---

As for `unique_ptr`, as you've noted, there exists a partial specialization that'll delete array types correctly. However, it does not store the length of the array, you'll need to store it separately and pass it around along with the `unique_ptr`. For one-line initialization you can use the same syntax as above.

```
std::unique_ptr<string[]> up( new string[len]{"John", "Paul", "Mary"} );
```

However, neither the `shared_ptr` nor the `unique_ptr` can be used with ranged-based for loops. The [specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) of a range for requires the operand to either be an array, or it must have `begin()` and `end()` member functions, or the begin and end iterators for the range must be obtainable by [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) using the expressions `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)` respectively. None of these conditions are satisfied by either the `shared_ptr` or the `unique_ptr` containing an array.

---

Unless you have a good reason not to, you should just use `std::vector<std::string>`, that'll save you the trouble of tracking array length separately. `std::array<std::string, N>>` is also another option if you know the length of the array at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

With C++17, `operator[]` is defined for `shared_ptr<T[]>` ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at)). Before that it was there for `unique_ptr`, but not for `shared_ptr`.

So, the following code will work.

```
std::shared_ptr<string[]> sp(new string[3]);
    sp[0] = "John";
    sp[1] = "Paul";
    sp[2] = "Mary";

    for(int i =0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        cout<<sp[i]<<"\n";
    }
```

Note that it is define for `shared_ptr<T[]>`, and not for `shared_ptr<T>`, i.e. when you have a dynamically allocated array. Also I have removed your custom deleter, as your's is similar to the default one which the compiler will use, you are however free to add it.

For your second query - being able to use new C++ for loop (range based for loop), you cannot use this smart pointer directly, since range based for loop works only on containers which have `begin()`, `end()`, `operator++`, `operator*()` , and, `operator!=`  defined ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)).
The simplest way is to use std::vector with pre-allocated size. eg. `vector<T> sp(3)`, or `vector<T> sp; sp.reserve(3)`. This will work as good as your smart pointers' approach. To get underlying memory you can use `vector<T>::data()` eg. `sp.data()`. This will give you a dynamic C array of 3 elements (n elements in general).

Answer (score 1):

> How to index into C++ `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` array?

You've already shown the code for `unique_ptr`.

This works for `shared_ptr`.

```
std::shared_ptr<string> sp( new string[3], []( string *p ) { delete[] p; } );
sp.get()[0] = "string 1";
sp.get()[1] = "string 2";
sp.get()[2] = "string 3";
```