# C++ Deleting a pointer to a object that contains another pointer

Tags: c++, object, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's say

```
class A {
  A* array;
public:
   A (){ 
    array= new A [4];
  }

  ~A (){
    delete array;
  }
}
```

How do we free an object if we create such an object on heap like

```
A* object_ptr =new A();
```

I'm a bit confused about freeing a pointer that points to an object containing another pointer.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things to note.

1. When deleting arrays you should use `[]`. For example: `delete [] array;`
2. When deleting pointers the destructor of the allocated object will get called. You would call from your code: `delete object_ptr;` to delete your pointer.

Another important point to be aware of is what happens when you copy your object. If your object ever gets copies you will have problems where one destructor deletes the pointers out from under another object. This is why `shared_ptr` is a good alternative to raw pointers (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used) on how to use `shared_ptr`).

Comment: If I assign the object_ptr to a new pointer, would it cause the same problem?

Comment: Yes. If you write: `A *a = new A(); A *b = a; delete a;` then `b`'s internal `array` will be deleted as well.

Comment: Hmm..also if an object is created by a method in stack with one of its fields created in the heap, does the memory in the heap get freed after?

Comment: Yeah the destructor of an object on the stack will be called when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: I have a program that returns`A object `,  and for some reason after the method, when the object is return to another variable `A new_object`, I can still access all the fields with no trouble. And I am confused as they should be gone by then since they are created instack...unless assign operator is  different when I use `A new_object = some_method()`

Comment: This is because of RVO (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization)

Answer (score 8):

Calling

```
delete object_ptr;
```

after

```
A* object_ptr =new A();
```

will invoke the destructor of the `A` pointed to by `object_ptr`. That means, if you fix your wrong

```
~A (){
  delete array;
}
```

to

```
~A (){
  delete[] array;
}
```

your code will be fine and the internal pointer is freed correctly.

However, you *really* should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`. It will make your life a whole lot easier. If you insist on `new[]`, read about [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: and `std::unique_ptr` (if available) instead of 'pure' pointers