# Accessing array of shared_ptr

Tags: c++

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
   std::shared_ptr<double> array (new double [256], [](double * d){
      delete [] d;
   });
}
```

I made a `shared_ptr` pointing into an array of doubles which has its own custom deleter.

Now how can I access the array? Let's say I wish to access the array at index `1`. I tried the usual "bracket method" but I get errors.

The word `array` points to its first element by default, but what if I want to access the 2nd element? Using increments and bracket gives me the "no match for operator" error.

Can someone explain to me what's happening under the hood?

I am asking this for research purposes, despite being aware that `unique_ptr` and `vector` will do a better job.

Comment: Sorry to ask but shouldn't it be `std::shared_ptr<double[]> array (new double [256], [](double * d){
      delete [] d;
   });` or    `std::shared_ptr<double> array (new double [256]);` in c++17 or even `std::shared_ptr<double> array = std::make_shared<double[]>(256);`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bracket notation is defined to work with pointer types (and you're right that, given array `array`, the expression `array` decays to an expression with such a type which points to the first element) but, despite its function, **`std::shared_ptr` is not a pointer type**.

You would have to [obtain the raw pointer first](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7be53fbf9011f5b):

```
array.get()[n];
```

Where `n` is, of course, a valid array subscript.

This is also the case with `std::unique_ptr` (though note that, [in that case, you do not need to supply your own deleter!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062069/560648)).

Comment: @CarloBrew Yes it is.

Comment: `(*array)[n]` this one gives me error btw. invalid type for subscript.

Comment: @CarloBrew yes and no. with unique_ptr you van specify the template parameter as `double[]` and not `double` and you don't have to provide destrcutor - the unique ptr will call `delete[]`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit here's what i tried `(*array)[0] = 50.0;`
`std::cout<<(*array)[0];`

Comment: @David: Yes my answer says that :)

Comment: @CarloBrew: Sorry, `(*array)[n]` was me being stupid. That's a `double`, not `double*`, of course. [You could use `(&*array)[n]`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff1acab24fcd7e5a), but I've decided to just remove that variant from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in C++17, support for array of shared_ptr like in unique_ptr( c++11).

```
int main()
{

   std::shared_ptr<double[]> array1 (new double [3]{4,5,6}, [](double * d){
   delete [] d;});

   std::unique_ptr<double[]> array2 (new double [3]{4,5,6}, [](double * d){
   delete [] d });
}
```