# Why cannot I use [] operator on std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]>?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm writing an application for Arduino (more precisely, Teensy). While compiling the following code (last pasted line):

```cpp
void executeActions(std::shared_ptr<unsigned char[]> actionData, const unsigned short actionBytes)
{
  unsigned short modifier = 0;
  Keyboard.set_modifier(modifier);

  int i = 0;
  while (i < actionBytes)
  {
    unsigned char action = actionData[i];
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::shared_ptr<unsigned char []>' and 'int')
```

For reference, mentioned `actionData` is initialized in the following way (then passed a couple of times):

```cpp
this->actionData = std::make_shared<unsigned char[]>(new unsigned char[this->actionBytes]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `shared_ptr` doesn't have a `[]`. You need to apply `[]` to the array referenced by the `sthared_ptr`.  [This help any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780262/accessing-array-of-shared-ptr)?

Comment: `shared_ptr` does have `operator[]` but only in C++17 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17 and later, `std::shared_ptr` has an [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at) (only when `T` is an array type).  This operator does not exist in C++11..14, which is apparently what you are compiling for, or at a cursory glance, Arduino does not fully support C++17.

Also:

```
std::make_shared<unsigned char[]>(new unsigned char[this->actionBytes])
```

should be:

```
std::make_shared<unsigned char[]>(actionBytes)
```

But that is only available in C++20 and later.

In this situation, I would suggest using `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `unsigned char[]` (you should not be using `new` manually anyway), eg:

```
actionData = std::make_shared<std::vector<unsigned char>>(actionBytes);
```

```
void executeActions(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned char>> actionData)
{
  unsigned short modifier = 0;
  Keyboard.set_modifier(modifier);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < actionData->size(); ++i)
  {
    unsigned char action = (*actionData)[i];
    ...
  }

  /* simpler:
  for (auto action : *actionData)
  {
    ...
  }
  */

  ...
}
```