# Vector reallocation causes malloc error

Tags: c++, vector, exif

I'm developing an application which reads Exif data from a JPEG file. The data is stored in a struct as below:

```
struct Metadata{
    int tagID = 0;
    std::string tagIDHex;
    int ifdNo = 0; // 0=IDF0, 1= Exif, 2=GPS, 3=Interop, 4 = IFD1
    BYTE* values;
    int noValues = 0;
    long valuesStart = 0; 
    int bytesPerValue = 1;
    long dataSize = 0;  // Generally bytesPerValue x noValues
    bool usesOffset = false; 
    /*If no bytes used by values is 4 or less, last 4 bytes in field hold actual values, 
    otherwise they point to location elsewhere in file */
    BYTE fieldData[12]; // Holds IFD field

    Metadata(BYTE* data, int ifd){
        ifdNo = ifd;
        tagID = data[0] * 256 + data[1];
        tagIDHex = intToHex(tagID);
        for (int b = 0; b < 12; b++){
            fieldData[b] = data[b];
        }
        noValues = (int)((fieldData[4] * std::pow(256, 3) + fieldData[5] * std::pow(256, 2) + fieldData[6] * std::pow(256, 1)
            + fieldData[7] * std::pow(256, 0)));
        // Look up datatype size based on TIFF spec where 1= BYTE, etc. 
        bytesPerValue = getBytesPerValue(fieldData[3]);
        dataSize = noValues*bytesPerValue; 
        usesOffset = (dataSize>4);
        if (usesOffset){
            values = new BYTE[noValues]; // will get populated later
        }
    }
};
```

The following piece of code loops through the fields held in the EXIF IFD and adds each one onto a vector named existingMetadataExif.

```
for (int f = 0; f < exifFields; f++){
    long tagAddress = exifStart + 2 + f * 12;
    Metadata m = Metadata(&file[tagAddress], 1);
    if (m.usesOffset){
        m.valuesStart = (int)(tiffStart + (m.fieldData[8] * std::pow(256, 3) + m.fieldData[9] * std::pow(256, 2) + m.fieldData[10] * std::pow(256, 1) + m.fieldData[11] * std::pow(256, 0)));
        for (int d = 0; d < (m.noValues*m.bytesPerValue); d++){
            m.values[d] = file[m.valuesStart + d];
        }
    }
    if (existingMetadataExif.size() >27){
        bool debug = true;
    }
    existingMetadataExif.push_back(m);
}
```

The code works fine for some files but I'm running into a memory problem with others. The problem seems to be tied into reallocation of the vector. All files work fine up to 28 elements. This seems to be the default reserved capacity for the vector. As each element is added up to 28, the size and capacity increment by one - 0/0, 1/1, 2/2, etc. When the size gets to 29, the capacity of the vector increases to 42 i.e. a 50% increase in the original capacity.

Whilst the error is always around the 28th/29th element, it is not totally consistent. one file increases the vector capacity to 42 and immediately crashes with a "triggered a breakpoint" exception, another file triggers the crash as soon as it hits the 28th element.

I have tried existingMetadataExif.reserve(42) inside the code but it makes no difference.

Whilst it seems that the size reallocation is the trigger point, I'm also wondering about the

```
 values = new BYTE[noValues]
```

line inside the struct. This is needed because each Metadata can contain a different number of values including none but I'm not directly deleting the arrays anywhere as they are needed until the application ends.

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 but not using any MS specific code as this application will eventually be ported to iOS.

## EDIT

Just to clarify - existingMetadataExif is the vector, declared elsewhere in the code and the error occurs at

```
 existingMetadataExif.push_back(m);
```

The lines

```
    if (existingMetadataExif.size() >27){
        bool debug = true;
    }
```

are irrelevant and can be ignored, I only out them in to help in my own debugging attempts.

Comment: 1 `new` + 0 `delete` = problems

Comment: I can't see you make any use of `std::vector` as stated in the title. Why?

Comment: #problems ~ exp(#`new[]`). Use `std::vector`, the 80s are over!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am guessing the vector use is `existingMetadataExif.push_back(m);` in the second code block.

Comment: A debugger and valgrind would probably have more info you may find useful.

Comment: Edited to clarify that existingMetadataExif is the vector.

Comment: Definitely caused by no copy constructor. Why did you use a new'd array instead of a vector for `values`, anyway? With a vector you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `new` is risky, even if you (think) you have the corresponding `delete`. In modern C++, you almost never need `new`.

((Actually, why not just get rid of the pointers and use `vector<BYTE>` instead?))

```
    if (usesOffset){
        values = new BYTE[noValues]; // will get populated later
    }
```

You should consider using a shared pointer here:

```
 #include<memory>
 ...
 std::shared_ptr<BYTE> values;
 ....
    if (usesOffset){
        values = std::shared_ptr<BYTE> ( new BYTE[noValues], std::default_delete<BYTE[]>() );
    }
```

Note the special deleter used here, because it's an array. ([For more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062069/146041)).

Assuming that compiles, and you are keen to ensure that each `Metadata` owns its own copy of the `values`, then you should use `unique_ptr` instead: (again, from that link above)

```
std::unique_ptr<BYTE> values;
...
    values = std::unique_ptr<BYTE[]> ( new BYTE[noValues] ); // this
                                     // will correctly call delete[]
```

The good news is that the use of unique_ptr will probably cause your code to fail to compile. I say good because it forces you to deal with copying. Either you implement a full copy constructor and copy-assignment operator, or you use `move` here:

```
    existingMetadataExif.push_back( std::move(m) );
```

Comment: I'm marking your answer as the correct one even though I'm not going to use  it. I was using pointers due to external constraints - having to pass data to/from another application developed in Objective-C. I was asked for all data transfer to be in pointers Thinking about it, however, I realised that there is nothing to stop me using vectors internally in my own code, it just means converting the information from/to pointers at the point of transfer. I've now done that and eliminated the problem.

I'm coming from C# and  pointers really do feel like the spawn of the devil :)

Answer (score 2):

Oups, you push onto a std container an object that contains a new allocated char array and only one constructor. It like shooting yourself in the foot ...

It can work, but you must be cautious :

- you must allocate the char array in constructor : fine
- you must deallocate it from destructor
- you must implement a copy constructor, allocate a new array in it and copy the content

That's what NathanOliver caller [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) in its comment

If you want to use C++ 11 move semantics, you can add a move constructor that copy the address of the array of original object and sets the pointer (in the original object) to 0 or nullptr. That way, you save an allocation and copy of the array.