# Why is there no specialisation for std::shared_ptr<T[]>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering why dynamic arrays are directly supported by `std::unique_ptr<>` but not by `std::shared_ptr<>`:

```
unique_ptr<int[]> ptr1(new int[n]); /// OK!
shared_ptr<int[]> ptr2(new int[n]); /// Incorrect: will not call delete[]
```

**Update:** I found out that the second line can be rewritten as:

```
 shared_ptr<int> ptr2(new int[n], default_delete<int[]>());
```

Now I am wondering what's going on behind the scene that makes `std::shared_ptr` works with the second approach and not in the way similar to `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: It's not about error message, it's about the correctness of the second line since it does not invokes delete[]

Comment: Don't you have to specify a deleter with `unique_ptr<int[],deleter>` (i.e. the `deleter` template parameter has no default)? That at least is what is suggested [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if am not mistaken.

Comment: Is your question essentially why there is a `unique_ptr<T[]>` specialisation, but no `shared_ptr<T[]>` specialisation?

Comment: @Walter yes! I'm wondering what's the technical reason?

Comment: Wellcome on stackoverflow! Good question.

Comment: @Vahid: Well, anyways, when you say that some code is incorrect on stackoverflow, unless its specifically a language lawyer question, it's a good idea to put the error message to help people figure out what's wrong. If you think your question is a language lawyer question you can tag it as such. (Even in a language lawyer question they give some kind of explanation usually. You've since modified this question so its someone moot now :) )

Comment: There is such specialization, in the [library fundamentals TS](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v1/fundamentals-ts.html#memory.smartptr.shared.obs).

Comment: ... except that it is named `std::experimental::shared_ptr<T[]>`.

Comment: See the second half of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062069/241631

Answer (score 3):

With `shared_ptr` you have to use a custom deleter that invokes `delete[]`, if you allocate the array with `new[]`.

Also, you have to be careful with up- and down-casting just as with raw pointers, so as not to invoke Undefined Behavior.

`unique_ptr` has direct support for arrays, so that when it knows that it holds a pointer to array you can't up- or down-cast, and the default deleter invokes `delete[]`.

Comment: I understand that, but is it due to a limitation of shared_ptr that it cannot utilize delete[] ?

Comment: @Vahid: `shared_ptr` came from the Boost library, which also has [`shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm). It's arguably a more clean division than the specializations of `unique_ptr`. But it means that `shared_ptr`, by design, doesn't actively support arrays. You have to cajole it into it, e.g. by using a custom deleter.

Comment: So, the reason is because of compatibility with the Boost lib, and because the `shared_array` has not been ported to STL yet, right?