# Using shared pointers for run time array allocations

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, raii

I have a C++ program where I need to allocate memory for a log (char*).

I read about `std::shared_ptr` and how they will handle deletion of memory once scope is left.

Will the code below automatically free the log buffer after the scope is left?

```
std::shared_ptr< char * > pLog = 
    std::shared_ptr< char * > ( new char[logLength+1] );
```

I know it might be somewhat simple, but I'm not quite sure how to confirm if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shared\_ptr to an array : should it be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used)

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is difficult to use with dynamic arrays; `std::shared_ptr<T>` by default models a single `T` object, not an array. (You would need to pass a suitable array deleter; e.g. [see the example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete).) `std::experimental::shared_ptr` supports array types `T[]` (like `std::unique_ptr`) and has a more convenient way of requesting the correct deleter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider to use `std::unique_ptr` instead. It will handle deletion of memory once scope is left, but in a more simpler way. Shared pointer creates and maintains a special descriptor object. You don't need that for a simple local buffer.

```
auto buff = std::make_unique<char[]>(buffSize);
```