# Using smart pointers for array

Tags: arrays, smart-pointers, c++03

How can I create a smart pointer to an array of double. I want to convert this expression :

```
double* darr = new double[N]; // Notice the square brackets
```

using smart pointer `auto_ptr`

the following instruction doesn't work:

```
auto_ptr<double[]> darrp(new double[N]);
```

Also how to get the values of the array using the smart pointer.

Thanks

Younès

Comment: What about it doesn't work? How do you usually get values out of a smart pointer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `std::auto_ptr`, as `auto_ptr` does not contain a specialization for array*

Although `auto_ptr` doesn't allow this, you can use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` for a smart pointer array:

```
#include <tr1/memory>
std::tr1::shared_ptr<double[]> d(new double[10]);
```

[This will compile](https://ideone.com/HVfW7i), but shared_ptr will incorrectly call `delete` (instead of `delete[]`) on your array which is undesirable, so you will need to provide a custom deleter.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062069/4143855) here provides the code that you will need (copied verbatim), although the answer is for C++11:

```
template< typename T >
struct array_deleter
{
  void operator ()( T const * p)
  { 
    delete[] p; 
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10], array_deleter<int>() );
```

Which for you, means you will need:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<double> d( new double[10], array_deleter<double>() );
```

To access the elements in your smart pointer array, you will first need to use [`get()` to dereference the smart pointer to obtain the raw pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get):

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<double> d( new double[10], array_deleter<double>() );
for (size_t n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
{
    d.get()[n] = 0.2 * n;
    std::cout << d.get()[n] << std::endl;
}
```

* Although your question is about C++03, it's worth noting that [std::unique_ptr does contain partial specialization for an array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), allowing this:

```
std::unique_ptr<double[]> d(new double[10]); // this will correctly call delete[]
```