# Treat C array name as raw pointer and copy to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, shared-ptr

Given that an array name is implicitly converted to a pointer, how do I copy a position of said array into a std::shared_ptr?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int arr[3] = {7, 8, 9};
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl; //-> 7

    std::shared_ptr<int> arr_ptr(arr); // Core dumped
    std::shared_ptr<int> arr_ptr(&arr[0]); // Core dumped

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This confuses me, because there is a legal constructor from a raw pointer in the specification:

```
template <class U> explicit shared_ptr (U* p);
```

Why can't I create a shared_ptr to this array position?

Ref:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/

Thx Keith :^)

Comment: Don't do that. `shared_ptr` deletes the memory. You don't delete a statically defined array.

Comment: *"Given that an array name is a pointer"* No it's not.

Comment: @BaummitAugen How would you phrase that part of the question?

Comment: @user3386109 Arrays can be implicitly converted or decay to pointers, but they are not pointers themselves.

Comment: Side-note: Even if you dynamically allocated the array memory with `new`, [`shared_ptr` must be customized to make it call `delete[]` properly instead of `delete`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062069/364696), so this is doubly-wrong.

Comment: Given that `std::shared_ptr` implies ownership, why do you try to make one from the address of something with automatic storage duration to begin with?

Comment: Perhaps a better question (for a different thread) would be if/how smart pointers can be used with raw pointers that can't be fully converted at this time.

Comment: Note some APIs may force you into using shared pointers when you'd rather stay static. Use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) to satisfy those folk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shared_ptr<>` does something what we call in C++ as **RAII**. It owns up the memory and tries to clean when getting out of scope.

An example with `placement new` will explain what is happening over here

```
int main()
{
    // Allocate memory in stack
    char memory[4];
    // use stack memory to allocate the intMem
    int *intMem = new (&memory) int;

    // delete the memory allocated in stack
    delete intMem; // Unexpected Behaviour

    return 0;
}
```

In your code

```
std::shared_ptr<int> arr_ptr(arr); // Core dumped
```

This line is equivalent to what we did with placement new above. The problem is not in this line. but happens at the end of main when the local variable including the `shared_ptr` goes out of the scope.

Comment: So, with old code that uses raw pointers, it is best to stay with them, until the system can be refactored using smart pointers? In other words, is it a bad idea to mix raw and smart, trying to manually wrap raw as smart pointers?

Comment: @Kmiklas  I generally avoid having generic rules or statements in programming. But your statement is valid in most of the cases. In C++11 onward, the best way to create is using make_shared()

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is statically allocated on the stack, not dynamically with `new`. Once the shared pointer exits scope, it will attempt to call `delete` on that pointer. Since the pointer references memory that was not allocated with `new`, the results are undefined.

`std::shared_ptr<>` for all intents and purposes is used for managing ownership of memory, which would otherwise be tedious to do manually. In this case, the compiler automatically manages the memory using stack frames.