# Using make_shared with char[] or int[]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, shared

Can you tell me if this works in VS2015 ?

```
shared_ptr< char> buffer( make_shared< array< char,10>>() , [] (char *p){delete[] p; } );
```

or

```
shared_ptr< char> buffer( make_shared< array< int,10>>() ,default_delete< int[]>());
```

Comment: try it and see?   There are online compilers if you don't have a copy handy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't support the C++17 standard. Prior to C++17 standard you can't have the `std::shared_ptr<T[]>` pointer. But even in C++17 the [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) function doesn't support array types so you would have to use the [boost::make_shared](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html) instead. Another alternative is to use the unique pointer in combination with the [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) which does support the array types. This again might not be a good idea as pointed out by Scot Meyers in his "Effective
Modern C++" book:

> The existence of std::unique_ptr for arrays should be of only
>   intellectual interest to you, because std::array, std::vector, and
>   std::string are virtually always better data structure choices than
>   raw arrays.

Comment: You might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used/13062069#13062069) as was suggested to me by @Baum mit Augen.

Comment: That answer uses explicit new, and my problem here is to get rid of it. 
  std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>()); // works fine in VS2015. Is it possible to get rid of the explicit new using make_shared ? Thanks