# Is shared_ptr broken for polymorphism

Tags: c++11, c++14

I heard that shared_ptr should not be used with arrays in C++11 and C++14 because it has issues with polymorphism and derived objects with certain compilers and that there are new proposals to fix this.

Is this true?

Comment: Do you have sources for these claims?

Comment: Arrays and polymorphism don't mix. I'm not sure what shared_ptr has to do with this. Can you be more specific about the issues?

Comment: i think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used will be helpful for you